# How to use TODAY() function with GOOGLEFINANCE() function in GoogleSheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula, google-finance

I am trying to create a sheet with stock data from the current day and yesterday.

Neither this:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE(B2;"price";TODAY())
```

Nor this:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE(B2;"price";DATE(YEAR(TODAY());MONTH(TODAY());DAY(TODAY())))
```

works.

But this does:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE(B2;"price";DATE(2020;1;17))
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Make another cell with the formula `TODAY()`. For ex. `A1: =TODAY()`.

Then `A2: =GOOGLEFINANCE(B2;"price";$A$1)`

Answer (score 0):

I have stocks in columns. 1 option is to simply hide the date columns! :-)